# node modules\ibm_db\build\release\odbc_bindings.node is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error Error status 0xc000012f

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, db2, odbc

As a backend newbie, I was tasked to update/make some adjustments to a 6 year old loopback/angular app. It has a couple of connections to external databases. One is a SOAP call and the other is an IBM DB2 connection.

I wanted to update the app to version 20.2.0 or as close to that.

Every time I try to `npm start` I get a Windows error popup that says

> \?\C:\Users\Me\MyProject\node
> modules\ibm_db\build\release\odbc_bindings.node  is either not
> designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the
> program again using the original installation media or contact your
> system administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status
> 0xc000012f

I found the odbc_bindings.node file , and it exists however it's not human readable.

```
Current Specs: Angular CLI: 16.1.1
typescript:  4.9.5
Node: 20.2.0 
Package Manager: npm 9.6.6
OS: win32 x64
```

The original attempt was on a 64 bit Windows 10 pro.
It's up and running on Node 8.12.0 with no problems.

I have reinstalled my node modules and tried it on another Windows machine as well with the same  result.

How can I bypass this error?

Comment: If the problem symptom is happening only on a single workstation, one possibility is that there is a conflict in versions of the mvscrt*.dll msvcrp*.dll that are on that workstation. Suggest you compare the versions (dates etc) of these DLLs between the working and the failing machines.  However, other causes are possible.